# Filtering between two datefield on django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model like:

```
class FeaturedGroup(models.Model):
'''
Featured Group. Here we store the diferents groups of featureds items
'''
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="upload", default="img-tmp/featured_category.png")
items = models.ManyToManyField('FeaturedItem', blank=True, null=True)
cnt_show = models.IntegerField(_('Quantity of items'))
cnt_max = models.IntegerField(_('Max items'))
rotation_time = models.IntegerField()
price = CurrencyField(_("Price for each Freatured item"), decimal_places=2,
              max_digits=8, blank=True, null=True,
              help_text=_("Enter the price of the each featured item"))
```

And I have a method inside that class which is:

```
def all_items(self, limit=False):
    key = 'featured_all_items_%(limit)s_%(id)s'%{'id':self.id, 'limit':limit}
    items = cache.get(key)
    if not items:
        featured = self.items.filter(date_from=datetime.date.today)
        featured = featured.order_by('-print_count', 'id')
        if limit:
            featured = featured[:self.cnt_show]
        items = []
        for item in featured:
            item.print_count += 1
            items.append(item.get_object())
            item.get_object()
            item.save()
        cache.set(key, items, settings.CACHE_TIME)
    return items
```

The problem is that line with self.items.filter(date_from=datetime.date.today) because if I have a product which for example date_from is a value which represents yesterday but date_to is a value which represents tomorrow, today it will still be valid, but with that line it doesnt.

I've tried with range but I've failed miserably. Any hint?

Comment: You can't just do <= one and >= the other?

Comment: hmm you mean: 

    featured = self.items.filter(date_from__gt=datetime.date.today)
    featured = featured.filter(date_to__lt=datetime.date.today)

I wonder if exists some more elegant instead of doing that manually.

Comment: `featured = self.iterms.filter(date_from__lte=today, date_to__gte=today)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ignacio was right.

featured = self.items.filter(date_from__lte=today, date_to__gte=today)

Did the trick